# Pygame error in Python 3.4

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

The error is on the line import pygame:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

from this line in pygame _ init_ :

```
from pygame.base import *
```

I am using Python 3.4 and Pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2.msi

Answer (score 4):

It seems no official Pygame release is compatible with Python 3.4 at the moment. You could downgrade your Python (to 3.2 or 2.7) or use an unofficial Pygame release, like the ones hosted [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

Either way, the issue is not related to Pycharm.

**Update**: Recently (December 2016), PyGame has come back to life. There are now official PyGame downloads for all current Python versions [on Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygame).

Comment: which unofficial one should i use?

Comment: @Emily The one for Python 3.4. You'll have to Ctrl+F `pygame‑1.9.2a0.win32‑py3.4.exe` on the page, since the links invoke some JS and can't be hotlinked here.

Comment: @Player72: Guess they changed the names. But CPython **is** mainstream Python, of which 3.4 is the most recent branch, so shouldn't really matter.